# No Such Module Found adding dependency in Podspec

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, cocoapods

I am creating a framework in iOS Using Swift. I have created the podspec file and put the dependency of googlemap in my framework.

When I am trying to install the my framework in sample application,It shows "No Such Module Find" for "GooogleMaps". Please let me how to link google maps in my framework so any application when install my cocoapod will automatically get GoogleMaps without any error.

Answer (score 3):

If you have created a `pod` and in your `.podspec` file you are trying to add a `dependency` (like Alamofire, RealmSwift..) after that you should **go to the `Example/..` folder and** **do a `pod install` to make the dependencies required from the .podspec of your custom `pod` visible** to the .swift files in your custom pod/framework.

A typical example of a pod project folder hierarchy would be:

```
- SMCustomPod/
  - _Pods.xcodeproj
  - Example/ // <-- do a pod install under this folder in order to get the dependencies declared in your .podspec
    - Podfile
    - SMCustomPod.xcodeproj
    - SMCustomPod.xcworkspace
  - SMCustomPod/
    - Classes/ // <-- folder with pod specific logic that also uses Alamofire
    - Assets/
  - SMCustomPod.podspec  // <-- your podspec with dependencies (Alamofire..)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off try to clean the project by

Command + Shift + Options + K

If I'm not mistaken, GoogleMaps framework is built from Objective-C so if there's still a problem then do the following steps:

Create a bridging header file which you can trigger and setup automatically by creating a dummy Objective-C class in your Swift project. Xcode will then ask you if you would want to create a bridging header, click yes. Delete the dummy class you created after.

Configure the header search path to point the Pods with recursion

Do a clean-build.

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

## platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Circle' do 
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

# Pods for Circle --------->>>>>>>>>. **Your Project name**

pod 'GoogleMaps'

pod 'GooglePlaces'

end